# Strange UI behavior after double-click

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, knockout.js

I have HTML code which utilize KnockoutJS for data binding and DOM manipulation. One of them is to highlight (single-click) and execute an action on double-click. All works fine except after double-click and hiding and showing some DIVs first word in a new spawned DIV is highlighted no clue why.

[image]

Code for highlighting and selection looks like:

```
 <tr data-bind="attr: { id: resource.id}, 
                css: {'isSelected':$root.selRow() == $data}, 
                click: $parent.highlightRow.bind($parent), 
                event : { dblclick: $parent.selectRow.bind($parent) }" >
```

I have tired to "unselect" it by executing `click()` event on a highlighted element but looks like is not working

```
    setTimeout(function(){
            $(".first_name").click();
            console.log("Clicked!");
        }, 3000);
```

Comment: The default behavior when double clicking on any text is to highlight the word. You can try adding "user-select: none;" to your CSS to prevent it, but it will also prevent the user from purposely highlighting the text to copy it.

Comment: @JasonSpake I have updated OP with my idea but it still stays highlighted

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mentioned which browser your are using here.

Please update the css with following styles for different browsers:

```
-webkit-user-select: none; /* webkit (safari, chrome) browsers */
-moz-user-select: none; /* mozilla browsers */
-khtml-user-select: none; /* webkit (konqueror) browsers */
-ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+ */
```

Comment: This solution is good when you want to disable user selection for the whole page (or spawned modal) as highlighting will occur on any first word not effected by those CSS changes

Comment: You can apply the above style selectively to the element where you want the behaviour https://jsfiddle.net/n46z0dwb

Comment: But as I have mentioned above - highlighting will appear on any next text not affected by CSS.